# Como puedo mostrar los valores que se guardan en el ciclo for desde consola C#

Tags: c#, bucle-for

Ingresar 5 números y mostrar en pantalla

```
        int n=1;

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dame un numero");
                n = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual seria el problema, porque justamente estas mostrando algo por consola, al hacer Console.WriteLine...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Para tu solución te aconsejo que carges los valores en un Array para recorrerlo posteriormente, esto te permitira al igual que imprimirlos todos juntos manipularlos a posteriori si fuese necesario, a continuación te aporto una solución

```
 ArrayList numeros = new ArrayList();

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dame un numero");
            numeros.Add(Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine()));

        }
            foreach (var numero in numeros)
            {
                Console.Write(numero);
            }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Es mas recomendable utililizar una Lista (List<T>), Con ArrayList hay boxing.